# Cannot find Class XXX for bean with the name XXX defined in ServletContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing a Spring MVC and stuck with the below error:

> 18:34:44,999 WARN 
>   [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]
>   (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception encountered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [com.icumed.beans.RequestInterfaceImpl] for bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.requestscope' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/FetchDevice-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.icumed.beans.RequestInterfaceImpl from [Module
>   "deployment.6.BeanScopingRequestSession.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader] Related cause:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [com.icumed.beans.RequestInterfaceImpl] for bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.requestscope' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/FetchDevice-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.icumed.beans.RequestInterfaceImpl from [Module
>   "deployment.6.BeanScopingRequestSession.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader] Related cause:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [com.icumed.beans.SessionInterfaceImpl] for bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.sessionscope' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/FetchDevice-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.icumed.beans.SessionInterfaceImpl from [Module
>   "deployment.6.BeanScopingRequestSession.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]

**My Directory Structure:**

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ICUMED-Req-Session-scope</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FetchDevice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FetchDevice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**FetchDevice-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.icumed.beans" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="requestscope" class="com.icumed.beans.RequestInterfaceImpl" scope="request">
  <constructor-arg value="Device1"/>
   <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionscope" class="com.icumed.beans.SessionInterfaceImpl" scope="session">
  <constructor-arg value="Device2"/>
   <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**TestController.java**

```
package com.icumed.beans;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private RequestInterfaceImpl requestInterfaceImpl;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionInterfaceImpl sessionInterfaceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String fetchDevice(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("requestscopedData", requestInterfaceImpl.getDeviceName());
        model.addAttribute("sessionscopedData", sessionInterfaceImpl.getDeviceName());

        /* return to view "hello.jsp" */
        return "device";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
 you can change your filter. Sometimes it needs those.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filterclass>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>      //filter path
</filter-mapping>
```

Second:
  you know `RequestInterfaceImpl` is `@Autowired`. It needs proxy;
you set `proxy-target-class="false"`, so it will use JDK proxy, not CGLib.

And you can do this:

```
@Autowired(required=true)
private RequestInterface requestInterface;   // use its interface, not impl
```

Or you can set `proxy-target-class="true"`. I think it's wrong because of proxy!

Comment: :This helped. Like you mentioned Have set proxy-target-class="true". Also while autowiring in TestController, i used qualifier to point to appropriate beanId